# Hipervínculo en el título de una clase en un diagrama UML usando tikz-uml

Tags: latex

Estoy usando el paquete tikz-uml (descargar desde [AQUÍ](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en&id=download) el .sty y la documentación) para generar diagramas de clases UML. En el siguiente código hay 2 líneas de código comentadas, una compila y la otra no (descomentar una u la otra). La primera es la que quiero que funcione, dejando en el título del bloque un hipervínculo a otro punto del documento. La segunda línea compila, pero no satisface el requerimiento (dejando un hipervínculo en la sección de atributos del bloque). Quiero saber si es posible de alguna manera (modificar en algún punto el tikz-uml.sty o mediante algún truco) permitir el funcionamiento de la primera línea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Diagram}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  %\umlclass{\hyperlink{desc:TMyClass}{TMyClass}}{Atributos}{Métodos} %Deja colgado el compilador
  %\umlclass{TMyClass}{\hyperlink{desc:TMyClass}{Atributos}}{Métodos} %Funciona correctamente
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{Description}
\label{desc:TMyClass}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece complicado lo que buscas. Mirando el código de `tikz-uml.sty` se ve que el primer parámetro que le pasas a `\umlclass` es procesado internamente de varias formas (sustituyendo ciertos caracteres como dos puntos o guión bajo, por otros), para crear con ellos lo que llama el `\tikzUmlClassNodeName`. Esta macro la usa después tanto para darle un nombre al nodo tikz que va a crear, como para escribir en negrita la "cabecera" de esa clase.

La parte donde irá el texto en negrita perfectamente podría contener hiperenlaces, pero la parte que es el nombre del nodo no. Además seguramente el preprocesamiento que hace de ese nombre no es compatible con la existencia de un `\hyperlink` en él.

Una solución "rápida y sucia", que seguramente introducirá efectos secundarios imprevistos pero que a mi de momento me ha funcionado, sería modificar el comando `\umlclass` para que acepte un parámetro adicional. De este modo se separaría el nombre del nodo tikz (que seguiría siendo el primer parámetro y no admitiría hiperenlaces en él), del texto mostrado en ese nodo (que pondríamos en el parámetro adicional y que sí podría contener hiperenlaces).

Por desgracia no podemos usar para ello el "parámetro opcional" que admiten algunos comandos latex (que va entre corchetes en vez de llaves), porque `\umclass` ya está usando ese parámetro opcional para otra cosa. Así que la solución más simple y que menos cambios implica sería pasarle el parámetro adicional como último parámetro.

De este modo podríamos usar ese nuevo comando:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\umlclass{TMyClass}{Atributos}{Métodos}{\hyperlink{desc:TMyClass}{TMyClass}}
\umlclass[x=5]{TMyClass2}{Atributos}{Métodos}{\hyperlink{desc:TMyClass}{TMyClass'}}
\draw[->] (TMyClass) -- (TMyClass2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Observa cómo el primer parámetro de `\umlclass` es una simple cadena, que se usa para dar nombre al nodo por si luego quieres unirlo con flechas a otros nodos. El último parámetro sería el texto que aparecerá en el diagrama y ahí ya se puede poner `\hyperlink`.

Naturalmente para que lo anterior funcione hay que modificar `tikz-uml.sty`. Estas serían las modificaciones necesarias:

1. La línea que ponía `\newcommand{\umlclass}[4][]` debe poner ahora `\newcommand{\umlclass}[5][]`, pues recibe un parámetro más.
2. Todas las líneas en que aparecía `\textbf{\tikzUmlClassNodeName}` se cambian para que aparezca `\textbf{#5}`

Con estos cambios el ejemplo anterior ya compila correctamente. Pero si tu diagrama es más complejo y usa otras macros, habría que hacer más modificaciones. Deberías buscar todos los puntos dentro de `tikz-uml.sty` que "llaman" a `\umlclass` y modificarlos para que llamen con un parámetro adicional. Por ejemplo, en la definción de `\umlabstract`, donde ponía `\umlclass[type=abstract,#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}%` debes poner `\umlclass[type=abstract,#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}{#2}%` para pasarle como parámetro adicional el mismo que le pasas como primer parámetro. A menos que quieras modificar la macro `\umlabstract` para que reciba también cinco parámetros (por si quieres usar hiperenlaces también en ellas).

La solución es más bien frágil. No sé qué otros efectos secundarios pueda causar. Pero en fin, es lo que has pedido, un "truco".

En [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/jyrmfxzgkmby) tienes una demo funcionando. Pego una imagen. Los títulos de las clases son clickables y llevan a otra página (aunque no en esta imagen, claro).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, funciona para mis efectos, como no estoy muy interiorizado en programación avanzada de latex me hubiera sido muy difícil siquiera haber pensado en esta solución. Muy bien explicado, muchas gracias.